# MacOS - NSWindowController not loading NSViewController after export

Tags: macos, nsviewcontroller, nswindowcontroller

I am building a software that uses storyboard and initializes a `NSWindowController` with the script below:

```
NSStoryboard *storyboard = [NSStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
self.windowController = [storyboard instantiateControllerWithIdentifier:@"FooWindowController"];
[self.windowController.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
[self.windowController.window setLevel:NSStatusWindowLevel];
[self.windowController.window setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"my_app", nil)];
[self.windowController showWindow: self];
```

The Storyboard:

[image]

This configuration is working perfectly when compiling both in debug and release mode, in any language (yes I only have a single Storyboard).

But when I archive it and sign with Apple, the storyboard is gone and it's only drawing the Window Controller. 
I checked if it's not a possible conflict with "another lost localized storyboard" but it's not, I tested it changing the theme and some settings of the Window Controller. These changes were reflected in the signed build, but the ViewController is still missing.

Any idea of what is happening?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe check to see if the Storyboard is present in `Build Phases` > `Copy Bundle Resources`  or you could try removing and re-adding it.

Comment: Tried this multiple times, screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/IBPSaix

Comment: It does appear your Storyboard in the Project Navigator is dimmed out? Maybe that's just how it looks in dark mode perhaps.

Comment: It's not, don't know what happened on the screenshot :p

Comment: My only other suggestion would be to delete your `Derived Data`, clean and try archiving again.

Comment: Tried too. I will try to rebuild the storyboard.

Comment: Just to remember, my Application has no storyboard entry point.

Comment: @I'L'I I think I sorted it by rebuilding the storyboard, thanks anyway!